# Is that possible to use a same user control in a page for multiple times?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's all about the control id. I am developing chat function in my asp.net project. I need to show a chat div for a target user that the current user is chatting with. Each chat div is loaded a user control. I'm wondering if there are more than one control shows in a same web page, what is the control id. For example, there is a textbox in user control id="tb1". If there are two user controls in a page, do the two textbox share a same id? I'm asking because I found that, even two chat div shows up, the content in the div are same which I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same control as many times as you want in the same page.

Since each user control will have a different ID, the child controls within it will have a different id based off of the container control's id as long as all of them are server controls (i.e. have the runat="server" tag).

Comment: If I use $.load() method to load multiple pages which each has a same user control inside, is it still good?

Comment: @Steven Zack: Your previous comment lead me to believe that you are not loading user controls but rather pages. You cannot load asp .net user controls (files with the ascx extension) using JQuery's $.load() function.

Comment: @lcarus, you are right. I load page with .aspx extension, but the page has user control inside. So if I load sevral such pages, which each of them has same user control, is that still good?

Comment: @Steven Zack: Yes, that's still good but I have the feeling that you may be architecting your chat application wrong. Also, keep in mind that JQuery's $.load() function may sanitize the HTML rendered. Read here for details. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

No, the TextBoxes will not have the same ID. Because they are in different user controls, they will be assigned two different ClientIDs.

You can see the IDs of the controls by viewing the source of the page in the browser. The ClientID will look something like this: `ctl00_ContentBody_tb1_TextBox1`

Comment: Actually, if I load page has user control, I can not find their source code in view souce menu.

Comment: It won't look like the user control that you have in your markup. It will be the outputted HTML from your user control. You should be able to search on the ID that you assigned the user control, though. It will be embedded in the client ID.